# Embed a dashboard from PowerBi into Angular6 application

Tags: angular, azure, powerbi

I'm trying to embed Pwerbi report with Angular6 application. I read many article but none is for Angular 2 to 6. Can anyone please suggest me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the following example to embed your PowerBI report within an angular application.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Import your library
import { PowerBIModule } from 'angular2-powerbi';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,

    // Specify your library as an import
    PowerBIModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[`powerbi-angular-client`](https://github.com/diego-d5000/PowerBI-Angular2)

Comment: Thanks @Sajeetharan.

Comment: I'm thinking , Is this token not going to expire? I want something dynamic. That every time I publish my report it will auto update the dashboard of Angular application.